# Onclick is being called several times even when i have called it only once

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle

I have put this code inside the `resize` function in jQuery. But this click function is called multiple times. When i click on the desired link the toggle takes place many times

```
if ($(window).width() <=768){
    if ($('body').hasClass('page-search-ads')){
        if ($('#-clasifika-results-simple-search-form               img').hasClass('funnel')) {
        } else {
            $('#-clasifika-results-simple-search-form').append("<img class='funnel' src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/clasifika/images/filter.png'/>");
        }

        $('.funnel').click(function(){
            $('.vehicle-cat, .vehicle-brand, .city-name-filter, .vehicle-mileage,.overall-cat,.city-name,.boat-bed,.boat-type,.boat-brand,.nautical-length,.overall-year,.airplane-type,.fashion-cat,.airplane-brand,.airframe-time,.propeller-hours,.monthly-salary,.amount-slider,.area-slider').slideToggle();
            console.log("funnel click");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because the `resize()` event is fired once for *every* pixel the window is resized. Therefore you're attaching multiple `click` handlers when the resize occurs. You just need to move the `click` outside the `resize` handler, and use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768 && $('body').hasClass('page-search-ads') && !$('#-clasifika-results-simple-search-form img').hasClass('funnel')) {
        $('#-clasifika-results-simple-search-form').append("<img class='funnel' src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/clasifika/images/filter.png'/>");
    }
});

$('#-clasifika-results-simple-search-form').on('click', '.funnel', function(){
    $('.vehicle-cat, .vehicle-brand, .city-name-filter, .vehicle-mileage, .overall-cat, .city-name, .boat-bed, .boat-type, .boat-brand, .nautical-length, .overall-year, .airplane-type, .fashion-cat, .airplane-brand, .airframe-time, .propeller-hours, .monthly-salary, .amount-slider, .area-slider').slideToggle();
    console.log("funnel click");
});
```

I'd also suggest you look at using a common class or single containing element to group all the elements in the click handler, as that's about the biggest selector I've ever seen. Also, CSS media queries may be a better solution for the `resize()` logic too, assuming you're able to just show/hide the relevant element.